# Почему дура бывает набитая?

Tags: фразеология

Есть выражение "набитая дура".
Глядя на некоторых девиц, понимаешь, почему "набитая" (бессмысленный взгляд, который на тебя бросают в некоторых учреждениях в ответ на элементарные вопросы, сразу наводит на мысль о набитых тряпками куклах), но почему набитая именно дура?
Или так называли этих самых кукол?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раньше плюшевых мишек набивали опилками и было обзывательство "у тебя опилки в голове" - может, здесь что-нибудь родственное (с головой, набитой опилками)?

P.S. В словаре Михельсона (1904) предлагается сопоставить выражение "дурак набитый" с фразой: "Набили дурака, да и отпустили".